# Handling mouse input in a multi threaded game

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, mouseevent

First of all, I apologize for the unruliness of this question, I tried to explain everything that was essential without leaving anything important out or giving anything extra, but I may not have done the best job.  I would post code but there is just way too much of it tot be able to post.

I am developing a game in Java, using no external libraries.  I have a main class that also handles my Jframe.  It sets everything up, such as size, title, etc, then starts a new Thread that handles everything else that's not basic setup.  It's an loop that runs until the game is closed.  It basically consists of update, then render.  Those methods call the corresponding method in a state managing class, which contains an instance of a custom GUI class that I extend for all of my GUIs.  I have it declared as a GUI rather than one of GUI's subclasses so that whenever I need to switch GUIs I can simply swap in a new one seamlessly.  So the basic flow of the program is the threads update() -> state manager's update() -> GUI's update(), then the same thing for render.  So my question is, since I have the Jframe declared outside of my thread, what is the best way to pass mouse input into the thread?  If there was just a single object that I could grab and send into the GUI, it should be simple.  But since there could potentially be multiple MouseEvents coming from the MouseAdapter between each frame, I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this.  The best idea I've come up with was to make an array of MouseEvents, then iterate through it in the update method.  However, for some reason Eclipse kept giving me errors when. I tried to make the array, so I gave up on that in about a minute.

Comment: What is the core `Component` that actually renders everything to the screen?

Comment: The `JFrame` itself.  My main class extends `JFrame`, and implements Runnable.  It has a `Graphics` object that I set to `this.getGraphics()` in the constructor, and then draw to with the thread.

Comment: `this.getGraphics()` is not how painting should be done. Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting should be done and how painting works in Swing